# MySQL Update not updating any rows

Tags: mysql, sql-update

This is a weird issue I'm having, I have a table and try to do a MySQL-Update query, however, PHPMyAdmin keeps saying 0 rows affected.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=55069 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `userid`, `name`, `last_login`) VALUES
(1, 55068, 'temp', '2012-02-02 09:04:50');
```

Query:

```
UPDATE `users` SET name='xorinzor' AND last_login=NOW() WHERE userid='55068'
```

No errors are returned, just nothing is happening, got no clue why that would be.

Regards,
Jorin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your update sentence to:

```
UPDATE `users` SET password='encryptedthingy', name='xorinzor', last_login=NOW() 
 WHERE userid=55068
```

Your SQL syntax was wrong. If you want to update multiple fields at once, you should not separate them with `and` keyword but with `,`.

Also, make getting rid of single quotes for `'55068'` should help, since that column is a number. And `'55068'` is a string literal.

Make sure this sentence returns a value:

```
select * from `users` where userid=55068
```

Comment: This indeed did the trick, but why where there no error's returned?

Comment: The thing is that `password='encryptedthingy' and name='xorinzor' and last_login=NOW()` is a valid boolean expression in MySQL. It probably assigned that value to the first column of your table. Check the actual value after that sentence with `select * from users`.